# ASP.NET Website Code Changed - Error 503 and a mystery Error Page popping up

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, http-status-code-503, target-framework

I have a ASP.NET Website, which has been accessed by someone I don't know. My code has been altered in such a way, that whenever I open any page of my system in the browser, a simple HTML Page with an error message pops up.

Checking the Network Details on the Browser Page, tells me that the Status Code 503 is being returned everytime I am trying to run my application. Instead of showing the usual Error Message, my application is showing me this HTML Page with the error message that I previously mentioned.

I tried searching my entire solution for the name of the mystery HTML page, and trying to see where it's been included, but there were no entries by its name.

I checked the IIS settings too, but they seem to be fine.

The page that appears instead of whatever page I try to open, is named as app_offline.htm, and I can't see mention of it in any script or file.

I am unable to figure out where it's been fit in. Any solutions for this will be very helpful.

**Also getting targetFramework attribute unrecognized when trying the build in Visual Studio 2008. Tried reinstalling the .NET Framework and Registering IIS again. Did not work!

Help Please!!

Comment: what error message in popups you are getting?

Comment: Somebody has designed a simple HTML Page reading the error, "Entry Barred" and placed it there. This is the only content on the page placed in a blue background, and this is what is showing up!!